# Nextflow: Is an input file empty?

Tags: groovy, nextflow

This is really a Nextflow question. I have a process that produces a number of files, some will be empty. I need to detect which ones and the next process should skip processing them. Looked straightforward, but the code:

```
process demuxByPrimers {
    publishDir params.outdir

    input:
    file productFile from products

    output:
    file 'ITS*.fastq' into primers mode flatten

    when: 
    productFile.size() > 0

    script:
    println "Processing ${productFile}"
}
```

does not work well. Input files in the work directory are symbolic links and thus they are not empty... Any ideas on how to skip processing empty files?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative consists to apply a filter on the `products` channel eg.

```
process demuxByPrimers {
  publishDir params.outdir

  input:
  file productFile from products.filter{ it.size()>0 }

  output:
  file 'ITS*.fastq' into primers mode flatten

  script:
  println "Processing ${productFile}"
}
```

Comment: Because the at the time the script is evaluated, the symlinks are not yet created. However I agree that something confusing and that should be improved. You may want to report an issue.